# 描画を禁止したり解除する方法

Tags: vim

Vim Scriptで画面の書き換えを禁止する方法と解除する方法を教えてください。
大量の文字列を入力すると重たいので描画を止めておきたい。

秀丸マクロでいうとdisabledrawとenabledrawに相当することがやりたいです。
http://hidemaruo.mydns.jp:81/helpsite/hidemac/html/110_MacroStatement_disabledraw_enabledraw.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set lazyredraw
```

で、不要な再描画を避けられます。元に戻すには、

```
set nolazyredraw
```

とします。
参考リンク: http://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/options.html#%27lazyredraw%27